# Is it possible for node.js to import a java library

Tags: java, node.js

I have a nodejs application that has some expensive computations.  I'm thinking of doing this part in java so I can more easily take advantage of threading and math libraries.  Is there an easy way to have nodejs talk to external java libraries?

The java library will contain a loop that frequently calls javascript functions.  Will I see a big performance hit due to having these two libraries constantly cross talk (rather than packaging the entire task, sending it to the jvm, and then getting a result back)

Answer (score 4):

It may be better to just create a java server to do the computations and communicate with your node.js application over a messaging queue. Here is an example which shows how to do that - http://blog.james-carr.org/2010/09/09/rabbitmq-nodejs-and-java-goodness/

Comment: This was also my first thought but I feel there is too much to networking overhead for this particular problem. The problem has a loop with constant cross talk where java basically needs to almost constantly be evaluating some JS. Basically, it is a solution searching algorithm where the algorithm is implemented in java but some evaluation and mutation is in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look a [Vert.X](http://vertx.io/), which will let you mix and match JavaScript and Java as you see fit and communicate via a local message bus.