# Can a web application be developed using hybrid technologies?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, jsp, servlets

Is it possible to develop a web application using a mix of technologies like servlet and nodejs? Using servlets somewhere and nodejs at some other place when required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Read about microservices. Docker can come in handy;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, consider these two use cases.

**Use case 1 (Sub Domains)**

You want `www.example.com` to use PHP & MySQL for Wordpress, `api.example.com` to run on Nodejs & MongoDB and `coders.example.com` to use Servlets.

Here you'd code and start all servers (PHP, Nodejs & *Java server*) on their specific & different ports and configure a frontend server (like Nginx) to receive and redirect requests according to the subdomains specified.

**Use case 2 (In-App)**

You want a request to come inside your Nodejs application get processed and then trasfer data to another process (a running Java app) and wait for a response back so it can process to user.

This can be accomplished by Message ques or HTTP/web services.

Both of these services will help you share your data back and forth.

[Read more on Message ques](http://queues.io/)

[Read more on HTTP/Web services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)

**References**

[Is it possible for node.js to import a java library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27592344/2405689)

https://www.quora.com/How-does-Node-js-communicate-with-Java-applications

https://www.quora.com/topic/Message-Queuing